Symbolically find total derivative wrt time of scalar field property phi using Julia
This is the code that I have tried so far:
using Symbolics

# define the variables that define the spatial coordinates of the fluid particle
@variables t x(t) y(t) z(t)

# define the scalar field property 
@variables ϕ(x, y, z, t)


# find the total derivative of phi with respect to t
Dt = Differential(t)
Dϕ = Dt(ϕ)
expand_derivatives(Dϕ)


I am looking for a rendered output as shown below:


